# HTML with Perl script not returning to main page

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I am calling a perl script from the form in HTML file (**index.html**).

```
<form method="post" action="cgi-bin/test.pl">
  more cmds....
   <input type="submit" align="left" value="Submit">   
</form>
```

The perl scripts executes successfully. but it remains in `test.pl`.

It doesn't return back to `index.html`. there are many more actions to be done after the perl script.

How to return the execution pointer back to `index.html`?

Comment: Your script should redirect to html page (by javascript/header/meta tags). Btw, this is an ancient approach which even predates whole cgi wave at the end of last century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`CGI #Generating a Redirection Header`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER)

```
print CGI->redirect('http://somewhere.else/in/movie/land');
```

Or redirect using javascript's [`window.location`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

```
print CGI->header() . qq{
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.location.assign("http://somewhere.else/in/movie/land")
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>redirecting...</p>
</body>
</html>};
```